# Wot topology on $B(H)$ is not metrizable

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $H$ be a infinite dimensional Hilbert space and $B(H)$ be the space of bounded and linear operators on $H$. I know that weak operator topology (wot) and strong operator topology (sot) are metrisable on bounded subsets of $B(H)$. I think to show  wot is not metrisable on $B(H)$, I should show $B(H)$ is not first countable. But I do not have any idea to do it. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The proof of this is non trivial. For a hint, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/424876/weak-topology-on-an-infinite-dimensional-normed-vector-space-is-not-metrizable

Comment: @Crostul: But your hint is about weak topology, and my question is about weak operator topology. unfortunately, I can not know how to use it.

Comment: HINT: $B(H)$ is a Hilbert space.