# First countability, nets and sequences in the weak topology.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, weak-convergence, locally-convex-spaces

According to [this book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=qtEFCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA317&lpg=PA317&dq=%22We+may+deduce+from+this+that+the+weak+topology+is+Hausdorff+and+satisfies+the+first+axiom+of+countability%22&source=bl&ots=qVkEteMesZ&sig=uQh7oHh42170E2IKYiH5KkjQMGg&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj0p67Gx93RAhWLnJAKHSqfBAoQ6AEIGzAA#v=onepage&q=%22We%20may%20deduce%20from%20this%20that%20the%20weak%20topology%20is%20Hausdorff%20and%20satisfies%20the%20first%20axiom%20of%20countability%22&f=false) (see print below) the weak topology (as well as the weak* topology) is first countable. However the weak topology should be first countable only in the finite dimensional case. So, is the book wrong or am I missing something?

The book also says "with regard to convergence we may deal with 
sequences rather than nets". Is it wrong too?

[image]

Comment: If you consider sets of the form $N(0;x_1^*,\ldots,x_n^*,1/m)$ for $n,m \in \mathbb N$ you get a neighborhood basis for $0$.

Comment: @Epsilon this is only countable for a finite dimensional space , because then we have a finite basis for the space of functionals.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1417295/4280 as well.  Also http://math.stackexchange.com/a/424883/4280

Comment: So we do need nets instead of sequences, for this case.

Comment: conclusion:the book is wrong

Comment: Okay, true. I had somehow separable spaces in mind.

Comment: @Epsilon: Even for separable spaces, this is not enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say your book is plainly wrong. E.g., in every infinite dimensional Banach space equipped with the weak topology, there are sets which are sequentially closed, but not closed, see [Is the weak topology sequential on some infinite-dimensional Banach space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2029853/is-the-weak-topology-sequential-on-some-infinite-dimensional-banach-space). This cannot happen in a first countable space.